# R- Understading NA values in the result of akima::interp

Tags: r, interpolation

I have the following data frame

```
 ref_dat
             k Intensity Slope
1  0.021467214        33    16
2  0.012444759        33     8
3  0.006079156        33     4
4  0.003792025        33     2
5  0.022765086        47    16
6  0.017335375        47     8
7  0.007279113        47     4
8  0.003396341        47     2
9  0.034101951        75    16
10 0.023045525        75     8
11 0.009163758        75     4
12 0.003253822        75     2
13 0.039832629       110    16
14 0.029826826       110     8
15 0.010529787       110     4
16 0.002945170       110     2
17 0.042140630       155    16
18 0.032338534       155     8
19 0.013758171       155     4
20 0.002605399       155     2
```

I am trying to get the interpolated (and extrapolated) values of k for a given set of slope and intensity using `interp` function in `akima`, so I am doing the following.

my new slope

```
s=10
```

my new intensities

```
i=c(seq(0,50,5),rev(seq(0,50,5)))
```

and calculating new k values

```
k_new=interp(x=ref_dat$Intensity,y=ref_dat$Slope,z=ref_dat$k,xo=i,yo=s,extrap = FALSE)$z
```

and the result is

```
k_new
            [,1]
 [1,]         NA
 [2,]         NA
 [3,]         NA
 [4,]         NA
 [5,]         NA
 [6,]         NA
 [7,]         NA
 [8,] 0.01539903
 [9,] 0.01714568
[10,] 0.01850739
[11,] 0.01930460
[12,] 0.01930460
[13,]         NA
[14,]         NA
[15,]         NA
[16,]         NA
[17,]         NA
[18,]         NA
[19,]         NA
[20,]         NA
[21,]         NA
[22,]         NA
```

turning extrapolation on

```
k_new_ext=interp(x=ref_dat$Intensity,y=ref_dat$Slope,z=ref_dat$k,xo=i,yo=s,extrap = TRUE)$z
```

and the reult

```
k_new_ext
            [,1]
 [1,]         NA
 [2,]         NA
 [3,]         NA
 [4,]         NA
 [5,]         NA
 [6,]         NA
 [7,]         NA
 [8,] 0.01539903
 [9,] 0.01714568
[10,] 0.01850739
[11,] 0.01930460
[12,] 0.01930460
[13,]         NA
[14,]         NA
[15,]         NA
[16,]         NA
[17,]         NA
[18,]         NA
[19,]         NA
[20,]         NA
[21,]         NA
[22,]         NA
```

exploring the result a bit

```
cbind(i,k_new,k_new_ext)
       i                      
 [1,]  0         NA         NA
 [2,]  5         NA         NA
 [3,] 10         NA         NA
 [4,] 15         NA         NA
 [5,] 20         NA         NA
 [6,] 25         NA         NA
 [7,] 30         NA         NA
 [8,] 35 0.01539903 0.01539903
 [9,] 40 0.01714568 0.01714568
[10,] 45 0.01850739 0.01850739
[11,] 50 0.01930460 0.01930460
[12,] 50 0.01930460 0.01930460
[13,] 45         NA         NA
[14,] 40         NA         NA
[15,] 35         NA         NA
[16,] 30         NA         NA
[17,] 25         NA         NA
[18,] 20         NA         NA
[19,] 15         NA         NA
[20,] 10         NA         NA
[21,]  5         NA         NA
[22,]  0         NA         NA
```

Why I am getting NA values, even when the new intensity values are with in the range of values in `ref_dat`? Making `extrap=TRUE` doesn't solve my problem either.

Comment: See documentation. `If linear is TRUE (default), linear interpolation is used in the triangles bounded by data points. Cubic interpolation is done if linear is set to FALSE. If extrap is FALSE, z-values for points outside the convex hull are returned as NA. No extrapolation can be performed for the linear case.` Can't be done unless you set linear to F.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my issue. But I am still puzzled why there are two different `k` values (one of them is `NA`) for the same `i` value of 40 (and 35 too).

Comment: Also why I am getting `NA` values even when the i is with in the range defined in `ref_dat`? I presume convex hull kinda reduces the range where the values can be interpolated.