# Getting NA with Akima Interpolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I'm attempting to interpolate some gridded values I have to a point on a road segment using the akima packages interp function. The data points are not always all there due to the data being missing at those times. For example, see the graph below.

[image: ![Gridded Values]

The lat/lng points shown are those that have dBz values from my dataset (if there is no value, our database doesn't record an entry). My goal is to use this grid to interpolate a dBz value to a specific lat/lng point (i.e. latitude = 39.95045 and longitude = -86.3574)

My data is as follows...

```
mrms
   tstamp: POSIXct: format: "2018-06-09 16:56:00" ...
   dBz: int 27 26 50 ...
   latitude: num 39.9 39.9 39.9 ...
   longitude: num -86.4 -86.4 -86.4
```

If I subset my data for a specific time (because there are multiple entries per time stamp. My data looks like the following.

```
        tstamp     dBz  latitude    longitude

1   6/9/2018 16:58  50  39.92501    -86.37501
2   6/9/2018 16:58  52  39.93498    -86.36501
3   6/9/2018 16:58  29  39.93498    -86.355
4   6/9/2018 16:58  38  39.91499    -86.37501
5   6/9/2018 16:58  44  39.92501    -86.36501
6   6/9/2018 16:58  23  39.92501    -86.355
7   6/9/2018 16:58  52  39.93498    -86.37501
8   6/9/2018 16:58  50  39.94498    -86.36501
9   6/9/2018 16:58  23  39.90501    -86.36501
10  6/9/2018 16:58  51  39.94498    -86.37501
11  6/9/2018 16:58  18  39.90501    -86.37501
12  6/9/2018 16:58  37  39.91499    -86.36501
```

After subsetting the data, I run the following command ...

```
interpolated <- interp(x = mrms_sub$longitude, y = mrms_sub$latitude, z = mrms_sub$dBz, xo = road$longitude, yo = road$latitude, linear = TRUE)
```

Which produces x = num -86.4, y = num 40, and z = num NA

I have no clue why interp keeps producing an NA value. I had this method working previously when I read all of the data in through a csv file. I've checked over datatypes for my csv method vs pulling the data in from SQL Server into a dataframe and they're the same. Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

```
require(tidyverse)
require(RODBC)
require(akima)

##### Road Details #####
cnx_wx <- odbcConnect("dbName", uid = "", pwd = "")
cnx_rd <- odbcConnect("dbName", uid = "", pwd = "")

queryString <- 
  "SELECT
          XDSegID,
      RoadNumber,
      RoadName,
      Bearing,
      geog.EnvelopeCenter().STAsText() as roadCenter
    FROM [itsdb1].[inrix_xd].[dbo].[__xd] as inrix_xd
    WHERE XDSegID = 1363484955 AND version = '2018-04-25'"

road <- sqlQuery(cnx_rd, queryString)

#Massage road center lat long points
road$roadCenter <- gsub("POINT|\\(|\\)", "", road$roadCenter)
road = separate(road, roadCenter, into = c("junk", "longitude", "latitude"), sep = " ")
road$longitude <- as.numeric(road$longitude)
road$latitude <- as.numeric(road$latitude)


##### Speed Data #####
queryString <- 
  "SELECT
      CAST(tstamp as smalldatetime) as tstamp,
      xdid,
      speed,
      score,
      cvalue
    FROM itsdb1.inrix_xd.dbo.xdspeeds
    WHERE tstamp >= '2018-06-09 15:00:00' AND tstamp <= '2018-06-09 18:00:00'
    AND xdid = 1363484955
    ORDER BY tstamp"

speed <- sqlQuery(cnx_rd, queryString)
#attr(speed$tstamp, "tzone") <- "GMT"
odbcClose(cnx_rd)


##### MRMS Data #####
queryString <- 
  "SELECT
      CAST(tstamp as smalldatetime) as tstamp,
      dBz,
      latitude,
      longitude
    FROM weather_mrms.dbo.v_seamless_hsr
    WHERE tstamp >= '2018-06-09 15:00:00' AND tstamp <= '2018-06-09 18:00:00'
    AND latitude BETWEEN 39.90 AND 39.95 AND longitude BETWEEN -86.38 AND -86.29
    ORDER BY tstamp"

mrms <- sqlQuery(cnx_wx, queryString)
odbcClose(cnx_wx)


##### Combined Data #####
numOfwxLevels <- nlevels(as.factor(mrms$tstamp))

i <- 1
obsTime <- mrms$tstamp[2]

output <- data.frame(0,0)
colnames(output) <- c("tstamp", "Interpolated dBz")

while (i <= numOfwxLevels) {
  mrms_sub <- filter(mrms, mrms$tstamp == obsTime)

  interpolated <- akima::interp(x = mrms_sub$longitude, y = mrms_sub$latitude, z = mrms_sub$dBz,
                         xo = road$longitude, yo = road$latitude, linear = TRUE)

  val <- c(obsTime, interpolated$z)
  newTable <- rbind(output, val)
  obsTime <- obsTime + 120
  i <- i + 1

}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? And what is the `road` data?

Comment: I'm expecting some sort of dBz value around 40-50. I apologize for not making that clear in the first place. Is there anything else that I've left out?
EDIT -> The road data is just a data frame holding my lat and long point to interpolate to, it has some other information but none of that is important to the interpolation.

Comment: What are the points you are using to create the output grid though? I'm just trying to replicate it.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking, the point I'm using for the output grid is the road$longitude, road$latitude. There's only one point I'm interested in interpolating to so that one point is my "grid". Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to use the interp function, my apologies if that's the case. I'm still working to really get the hang of R.

Comment: What are those longitude and latitude values you are interested in?

Comment: Ah, I understand. Sorry about that, that was up towards the top of the question, here it is ->  latitude = 39.95045 and longitude = -86.3574

Answer (score 2):

Reading over the [help file for it](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/akima/akima.pdf) it brings up two things: 1) it recommends against `colinear` points, 2) it can't extrapolate using `linear interpolation`, which is why you're getting `NA` outside of your data.

If you use another interpolation it'll work, but I doubt that's what you want. You may have to look at another method.

```
df1terp2 <- interp(x = mrms_sub$longitude, y = mrms_sub$latitude, z = mrms_sub$dBz, xo = 39.95045, yo = -86.3574, linear = FALSE, extrap = TRUE)

$`x`
[1] 39.95045
$y
[1] -86.3574
$z
    [,1]
[1,] -78789.37
```

Comment: Did you do anything outside of what you wrote in your code block? The reason I ask is because if I copy and run your code, I still end up with NA for my z value.

Comment: No, but I see what you're saying. It I just run the `interp` in the console I get `NA` too. But if I store it to anything, it gives a value, which is odd. These [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364470/extrapolation-beyond-a-grid-of-data?rq=1) questions [may be some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003065/r-understading-na-values-in-the-result-of-akimainterp).

Comment: Even more odd, my code that used to work (for both linear = T and F) wasn't working anymore. I reloaded R studio and it's working now... I'm going to see if a restart is all I needed.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have done the trick. I'm editing the question with my full source code now.